# Poder parar una película reproducida con el modulo vlc de python

Tags: python

Tengo este codigo en python. Reproduce las películas pero no consigo poder pararlas o darles a pause.
Hay alguna manera en el código de hacerlo.
la pantalla la puedo poner en modo completo o pequeño pero no es posible parar la película cuando yo quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿media.pause() no funciona?

Comment: Ok, pero con esa opción no puedo para el video a mi antojo cuando yo quiero.

Comment: No conozco el modulo VLC, pero si puedes leer el teclado mientras se reproduce el video, puede interpretar la barra espaciadora como pause/play.

Comment: Buena idea. Lo probare y lo pondre si funciona. Gracias